# Current divider

Tags: current, resistors, parallel

I have a 12V DC 5A power supply and I would like to make a parallel circuit with a current division of 0.2A for the first branch and 4.8A for the second branch.
I figured I need to use resistors, are 510 ohm and 22 ohm are the correct value ? What wattage should I use ?

Latter on, I have to divide the second branch into 5 branches with equal amps, do I need resistors too ?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like a misconception about currents and power supplies here..

Comment: I smell an xy problem, why do you want to "divide amps"? It doesn't work like with voltage dividers...

Comment: You have to show us a schematic of what you're trying to achieve. Normally "current division" is not needed if you just want to power some devices. Explain to us in detail what you want to achieve because now the question is vague so you'll get vague answers.

Comment: I need to power an arduino and a led strip with the same power supply. I can't power the led strip with the arduino so I thought about a parallel circuit. The led strip need about 4A

Comment: Well. A *total* misconception, as I've predicted...

Comment: No need for special circuitry. If both devices can be powered by 12V you can just connect them directly to the supply and current will flow as required. I suggest to familiarize yourself some more with the basics of electrics.

Comment: @user126774 You don't need to divide the current. The loads will do that for you by drawing whatever current they sink. Just connect both loads to the 12V supply and you're good to go. But first, go and read up on voltage, current, resistance and Ohm's Law, so you can understand what you are doing. It's basic and *essential* theory.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Answer (score 1):

Add up all your maximum currents on each branch, and buy a power supply capable of providing the sum.  When you have that power supply, hook up all of your individual components in parallel, and each component will only take the current that it needs.  No need to divide.